# The element type "label" must be terminated by the matching end-tag

Tags: visualforce, error, bootstrap

I am trying to create a visualforce page with some bootstrap in it.
I can't understand the error I get on these lines of code, line 2, I get this message:

**Error: The element type "label" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".**

I think is correctly terminated, isn't it??

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rut">Rut Asugurado: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"/></span></label>
    <input type="rut" class="form-control" id="rut"/>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing the `span` tag two times: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"/></span>`

Just replace it with: `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>`

Answer (score 1):

You have a self closing span then  this

```
</span>
```

Remove the `</span>`

Answer (score 1):

`span` tag is not ended properly. Try below code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rut">Rut Asugurado: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></label>
    <input type="rut" class="form-control" id="rut"/> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a self-closing span tag followed by a close span tag. If you get rid of the extra `/`, you should be fine.